# How to share a video directly to facebook/instagram through a link as video which can be directly played using react-native

Tags: facebook, react-native, twitter, instagram

How to share a video directly to Facebook/Instagram/twitter through a link using react-native. I am using react-native-share to share videos on Instagram/Facebook but that is getting shared as a link, but I want to share them as a video as TikTok does.

How can I achieve that? I know it is able by converting it to base 64, so are there any libraries which convert links to base 64 directly?  Else I would need to download it first then retrieve it and then convert to base 64 then share it.

Please help!

Will Answer how I did it if some one needs the complete code:

```
shareURL = async (socialMedia) => {
        let facebook = socialMedia === 'facebook'
        let twitter = socialMedia === 'twitter'
        const { video, uploadingStatus } = this.state;

        this.setState({ isSliderModalVisible: true }, async () => {
            let uploadOptions = { fileCache: true, appendExt: 'mp4', timeout: 60000, indicator: true, IOSBackgroundTask: true, }
            const res = await RNFetchBlob.config(uploadOptions).fetch('GET', video, {})
                .progress((received, total) => {
                    this.setState({ uploadingStatus: (received / total) * 100 })
                    console.log('Progress', (received / total) * 100);
                })
            const filePath = res.path(); //to delete video
            const base64String = await res.base64();
            const url = `data:video/mp4;base64,${base64String}`;
            await RNFetchBlob.fs.unlink(filePath); //deleted the video from path of celebfie.
            this.setState({ isSliderModalVisible: false })
            setTimeout(() => {
                const shareOptions = {
                    title: 'Celebfie',
                    message: hashtags,
                    subject: 'Sharing my intro video which I recorded in Celebfie.',
                    url: url,
                    type: 'video/mp4',
                    social: facebook ? Share.Social.FACEBOOK : twitter ? Share.Social.TWITTER : Share.Social.INSTAGRAM
                };
                Share.shareSingle(shareOptions).then((res) => this.setState({ sharedVideoToSocialNetwork: true }))
                    .catch((err) => { Global.customToast('Video sharing failed.', 'failure') })
            })
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question here it is how it works :

```
shareURL = async (socialMedia) => {
        let facebook = socialMedia === 'facebook'
        let twitter = socialMedia === 'twitter'
        const { video, uploadingStatus } = this.state;

        this.setState({ isSliderModalVisible: true }, async () => {
            let uploadOptions = { fileCache: true, appendExt: 'mp4', timeout: 60000, indicator: true, IOSBackgroundTask: true, }
            const res = await RNFetchBlob.config(uploadOptions).fetch('GET', video, {})
                .progress((received, total) => {
                    this.setState({ uploadingStatus: (received / total) * 100 })
                    console.log('Progress', (received / total) * 100);
                })
            const filePath = res.path(); //to delete video
            const base64String = await res.base64();
            const url = `data:video/mp4;base64,${base64String}`;
            await RNFetchBlob.fs.unlink(filePath); //deleted the video from path of Sexy lady.
            this.setState({ isSliderModalVisible: false })
            setTimeout(() => {
                const shareOptions = {
                    title: 'Sexy Lady',
                    message: hashtags,
                    subject: 'Sharing my intro video which I recorded in Celebfie.',
                    url: url,
                    type: 'video/mp4',
                    social: facebook ? Share.Social.FACEBOOK : twitter ? Share.Social.TWITTER : Share.Social.INSTAGRAM
                };
                Share.shareSingle(shareOptions).then((res) => this.setState({ sharedVideoToSocialNetwork: true }))
                    .catch((err) => { Global.customToast('Video sharing failed.', 'failure') })
            })
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: is it working?? I am downloading a file from firebase. storage and then posting the file share. I tried multiple ways.Only thing works for me is share.open. Share.single option is not at all working

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this :

```js
Share.open(
      {
        message: `I have successfully Completed this course`,
        title: 'Share',
        url: 'file:///documents..',
        type: 'video/mp4',
      },
      {
        // Android only:
        dialogTitle: 'Share',
        // iOS only:
        excludedActivityTypes: ['com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToTwitter'],
      },
    );
```

Comment: the url specified is file but I have a URL like www.asw.mp4 something like this I don't have file

Comment: I'll give it a try.. Is the share from react native or is this a third party library react-native-share?

Comment: Sadly it didn't work! Still the video url is being posted not the video

Comment: For that, You need to add linkMetaData in options object

Comment: it is a iOS only feature which shall be used under activityItemSources